# A commutative ring in which every prime ideal is 2-generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with 1. There are some statements that tells us if prime ideals behave in certain way, then all the ideals will behave in that way. For example,

> If every prime ideal in $R$ is finitely generated, then every ideal in
>   $R$ is finitely generated.

Similarly, we have

> If every prime ideal in $R$ is principal, then every ideal in $R$ is
>   principal.

I am interested in understanding what happens when we consider ideals that are 2-generated (i.e. they have two generators). So my question is:

> If every prime ideal is 2-generated, then is it true that every ideal
>   in $R$ needs less than or equal to 2 generators?

If the answer is affirmative, I guess the natural generalization has also answer "yes".

> If every prime ideal is $k$-generated, then is it true that every
>   ideal in $R$ needs less than or equal to $k$ generators?

Thanks!

Comment: If you like this idea then you *have* to read [this paper](http://math.berkeley.edu/~mreyes/ams-oka2.pdf) by Lam and Reyes. Actually, I have a hard time not recommending this paper to everyone who knows what a prime ideal is...

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks for this interesting suggestion. So they are giving far-reaching generalization of the first two statements in my post. I shall read it!

Comment: When you finish it, read [this followup paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3701) also :)

Comment: @rschwieb: Haha _if_ I can finish it... That would be very first arxiv paper for me to read! Exciting! :)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ should be a counterexample. If I remember correctly, every prime ideal has one of the forms $(p)$, $(f)$ or $(p,f)$ where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is prime and $f$ is irreducible. In contrast to that, for any positive integer $n$ there is an ideal which needs $n$ generators.

Comment: @Dune: Could you elaborate on the last sentence? How do we construct an ideal which needs $n$ generators?

Comment: @Prism http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110458/construct-ideals-in-mathbb-zx-with-a-given-least-number-of-generators

Comment: @Dune I think since you're the first to bring up this nice example, you should have the credit of writing it up as a solution. Please do this so we can get it out of the unanswered queue :) You might also incorporate a pointer to [the fact about the prime ideals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx) of $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @rschwieb,YACP: Thank you for the links! I mentioned them in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is a summary of the above comments and some other threads mentioned there.

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ provides a counterexample to your question. To be precise, every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathbb{Z}[X]$ has one of the forms: $(0)$, $(p)$, $(f)$ or $(p,f)$ where $p$ is a prime number and $f$ is an irreducible polynomial (even modulo $p$). A proof has already been given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx). Particularly, every prime ideal is 2-generated.

On the other hand, the minimum number of generators of an arbitrary ideal is unbounded. In fact, for every positive integer $n$ there is an ideal $I \subset \mathbb{Z}[X]$ which needs exactly $n$ generators. Consider for example the ideal $I := (p,X)^n = (p^n, p^{n-1}X, \dots, pX^{n-1},X^n)$ which cannot be generated by fewer than $n+1$ elements. A proof has been given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110458/construct-ideals-in-mathbb-zx-with-a-given-least-number-of-generators).

Comment: Excellent example!